# How Do I make a Razor Form for a complex EF Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-2.1, razor-pages

I am beginning to wonder if what I am about to ask is even possible.. But it SHOULD be.

The MS examples are woefully short of what I am after so maybe EF isn't designed the way I thought. (BTW Scaffold for CRUD for each individual table works great. But it only does table level creation. I want something that manages the relation as an object.)

```
public class ContactPhone
{
    public ContactPhone(ContactPhone contactPhone)
    {
        Id = contactPhone.Id;
        ContactId = contactPhone.ContactId;
        ContactPhoneTypeId = contactPhone.ContactPhoneTypeId;
        Number = contactPhone.Number;
    }

    //private ContactPhone contactPhone;

    public ContactPhone()
    {
    }

    //public ContactPhone(ContactPhone contactPhone)
    //{
    //    this.contactPhone = contactPhone;
    //}

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }

    public int ContactPhoneTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ContactPhoneType ContactPhoneType { get; set; }

    public string Number { get; set; }
}


public class Contact
{
   public  Contact()
    {
        Phones = new List<ContactPhone>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int LocationAddressId { get; set; }
    public LocationAddress LocationAddress { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual SCPI_site_User User { get; set; }

    //public ICollection

    public List<ContactPhone> Phones { get; set; }
}
```

I know this is wrong but it kinda works...my assumption was that my Contact was persistent and passed back and forth between the Razor page, however that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
            public class CreateModel : PhoneTypesPageModel
            {
                private readonly SCPI_Site.Areas.SCPI_SiteContext _context;

                public CreateModel(SCPI_Site.Areas.SCPI_SiteContext context)
                {
                    _context = context;
                }
                [TempData]
                public string Message { get; set; }

                [BindProperty]
                public Contact Contact { get; set; }

                [BindProperty]
                public ContactPhone ContactPhone { get; set; }

                //public bool HasPhones => Contact.Phones.Count > 0;

                public IActionResult OnGet()
                {
                    PopulatePhoneTypeDropDownList(_context);
                    int userID = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();

                    if (Contact == null)
                    {
                        Contact = new Contact();
                    }
                    if (ContactPhone == null)
                    {
                        Contact = new Contact();
                    }

                    Contact.UserId = userID;
                    ViewData["UserId"] = userID;          
                    return Page();
                }

                public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string submit)
                {
                    int userID = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
                    Contact.UserId = userID;        

                    switch (submit)
                    {
                        case "AddPhone":
                            // (failed attempt) _context.ContactPhone.Add(ContactPhone);
                            Contact.Phones.Add(new ContactPhone(ContactPhone));
                            ContactPhone.Number = "";
                            return Page();


                        default:
                            //if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                            //{
                            //    return Page();
                            //}

                            _context.Contact.Add(Contact);
                            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                            Message = "Contact Created!";

                            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

HTML:

```
    @page

    @model SCPI_Site.Areas.ContactModel.Pages.Contacts.CreateModel

    @{
        //Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
        ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    }
    <div class="col">
        <h4>Contact</h4>
        <hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <form method="post">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Contact.UserId" />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label asp-for="Contact.FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                            <input asp-for="Contact.FirstName" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Contact.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label asp-for="Contact.LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                            <input asp-for="Contact.LastName" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Contact.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Contact.Email" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Contact.Email" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Contact.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Contact.LocationAddress.Address" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Contact.LocationAddress.Address" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Contact.LocationAddress.Address" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label asp-for="Contact.LocationAddress.City" class="control-label"></label>
                            <input asp-for="Contact.LocationAddress.City" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Contact.LocationAddress.City" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label asp-for="Contact.LocationAddress.State" class="control-label"></label>
                            <input asp-for="Contact.LocationAddress.State" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Contact.LocationAddress.State" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label asp-for="Contact.LocationAddress.PostalCode" class="control-label"></label>
                            <input asp-for="Contact.LocationAddress.PostalCode" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Contact.LocationAddress.PostalCode" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    @if (Model.Contact.Phones != null)
                    {
                        <hr />
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        Type
                                        @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contact.Phones[0].ContactPhoneType)*@
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Number
                                        @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contact.Phones[0].Number)*@
                                    </th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @if (Model.Contact.Phones != null)
                                {
                                    @foreach (var item in Model.Contact.Phones)
                                    {
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactPhoneType.Id)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a asp-page="../ContactPhones/Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                                                <a asp-page="../ContactPhones/Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                                                <a asp-page="../ContactPhones/Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    }
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    }
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>

                    <div id="pay-invoice" class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="card-title">
                                <input type="hidden" id="x_card_num" name="x_card_num" value="">
                                @*<partial name="../ContactPhones/Index" model=@Model />*@


                                @*First name:
                                <input type="text" name="A" value="<%= ViewData[" A"] %>" />
                                <br />
                                Last name:
                                <input type="text" name="B" value="<%= ViewData[" B"] %>" />
                                <br />
                                <input type="submit" value="Insert" />
                                <button type="submit" name="submit" value="add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Add another</button>*@



                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="ContactPhone.ContactId" />
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-7">
                                        <label asp-for="ContactPhone.Number" class="control-label"></label>
                                        <input asp-for="ContactPhone.Number" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="ContactPhone.Number" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                                        <label asp-for="ContactPhone.ContactPhoneType" class="control-label"></label>
                                        <select asp-for="ContactPhone.ContactPhoneTypeId" class="form-control"
                                                asp-items="@Model.PhoneTypeSL">
                                            @*<option value="">-- Select Type --</option>*@
                                        </select>
                                        <span asp-validation-for="ContactPhone.ContactPhoneTypeId" class="text-danger" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <button type="submit" name="submit" value="AddPhone" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-plus"> </span>  Add Phone Number</button>

                                @*<a asp-area="ContactsModel" asp-page="/ContactPhones/Create"> Add Phone Number</a>*@
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <p>

                        @*    <a asp-page="Create">Create New</a>*@
                    </p>

                    @*@Html.Hidden("Contact.UserId")   This breaks the validation*@
                    @*<div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Contact.UserId" class="control-label"></label>
                            <select asp-for="Contact.UserId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.UserId"></select>
                        </div>*@




                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    @section Scripts {
        @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
```

Create:

Given this little model, how do I create a razor page that will add phone records to the Contact object and capture the Contact Object data and create the entire model with one Save call. (manage the keys etc)

Now I could be way off base here but this type of scenario is what I would expect from an ORM. Frankly I'm not sure why anyone would build the EF and not provide this type of functionality. But likely I am missing something and I have poured over the MS docs many times searching for clues.

But it works that way in Django ;)

If there is even one example of this type of operation out there that isn't the same customer one dimensional example I would appreciate it.

Thanks
CB

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bind items to a property that's a collection of some kind, you need to add indexers to the name of the form fields or the expression that you pass to the `asp-for` attribute of a taghelper, beginning with `0`.

Here's a simpler model:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public int OrderItemId { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the PageModel:

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public Order Order { get; set; }

    public void OnPost()
    {

    }
}
```

Here is the form:

```
@page
@model CreateModel
@{
}

<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="Order.Customer" /><br />
    <input asp-for="Order.Items[0].Item" /><br/>
    <input asp-for="Order.Items[0].Price" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

That is all you need. The values from the form will automatically be bound to the `Order` property marked with the `[BindProperty]` attribute. If you pass that to EF, it will create and save an order, and then use the ID to create and save an `OrderItem`. If you want to allow the user to create more items, just increment the indexer by `1` for each item:

```
<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="Order.Customer" /><br />
    @for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    <input asp-for="Order.Items[i].Item" /><br/>
    <input asp-for="Order.Items[i].Price" />
    }
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Ref: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding#binding-complex-collections

Comment: Thanks for the post, so maybe my issue is with the EF. When I instantiate my contact, the list is null. Also I assumed I would need to post back every new phone( or in your case order )and popluate object instance. And I haven't found an example describing this well.

Comment: The model binder should instantiate your Contact object. And the phone list should never be null. It should be initiated to an empty collection. The constructor you posted ensures that. I didn't read all your code, so I may have missed a trick. All I did was try to explain how model binding works in Razor Pages. What you should perhaps do is provide the minimum amount of code to reproduce your issue, removing all the unnecessary stuff such as validators. comments, css etc.

Comment: Once again, many thanks for all of the help. I can't attach a picture of the screen I am trying to create... but suffice to say, my postback of the individual phone number (which I am adding in c# to the Contact list (instantiated and bound)) doesn't persist to the next postback, meaning when I display in a loop, the count is 1. when I add another, my bound Contact is empty when I return from HTML. Not sure if there is another full working example that you know of that shows how this was intended to be handled.-Cheers CB

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what the issue is. The requirement scenario you seem to be describing (create an object from posted values and save it to a database) is very simple, and requires hardly any code. If you want to update an existing object, you need to either retrieve the object from the database and and amend its properties, or use a stub to represent the object you want to update: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbset/modifying-data

Comment: I think my expectation is that the Contact Object I create persists on the server in relation to the client. But apparently may not be the case. So... what is the appropriate way to handle a form that posts back multiple times in order to create a complex object? And.. Do I need to keep a separate list for the dependent data (phones) and then assemble a DBSet<phones> before I save the complete object <phone>? Sorry, but things are not as I would assume and the docs are generally for very simple examples.

Comment: Indeed, even adding phone numbers to the _context does not persist. Is there no way to go back and forth to modify an object in a UI ?

Comment: No, the web is stateless. Your model is not persisted on the server unless you explicitly store it somewhere (cache, session, database). I'll update the answer with a fuller explanation.

Comment: Actually, you should have a `DbSet<ContactPhone>`, in which case you just need to add a new phone number with the correct `ContactId`.

Comment: I am now realizing some of my problems are preconceived from C++ and some other bad examples.... But with that in mind, I get that now I need to manage everything at the form level. In create mode there are no IDs at all.. and.. How would I dynamically add to that object model (form level) without posting back to the OnPostAsync() so I have a couple blank fields for phone and type, and I want the user to have the same crud look and feel but embedded in the CRUD create at the Phone level. (including the ability to edit and delete) basic UI stuff.. And thanks for all the help. I owe you a coffee

Comment: After 5 days of searching... found this:  
 https://patricjsson.wordpress.com/2015/05/25/asp-net-mvc-proper-model-binding-with-dynamic-form/   : I guess there is no way to manage the model form without using javascript? I've been object coding for 35 years and this seems incredibly tedious and shall I say 'backward' in terms of progress. This seems nightmarish for really large and complex models.... I  Kind of figured there would be a more elegant solution by now. If I am wrong please let me know.

Comment: If you want to add phone numbers at the same time as you create the contact, look at my original answer. If you want to add phone numbers to an existing contact, you need the ContactId. If you want to enable creation of a contact and its phone numbers asynchronously, you will need JS.